# Pyglet- Screen Flickering

Tags: python, pyglet

I am attempting to make a Langton's ant program using Python and Pyglet.  It would take to long to redraw all 62500 tiles in a 350 by 250 grid, so what I am doing is whenever I iterate the Langton's Ant part, I add the updated tiles to a list and when `on_draw()` is called, I draw the updated rectangles and clear the list.

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
    Ant.batch.draw() # Draw the grid spaces that were changed
    Ant.buffer = [] # Clear the updated grid space buffer

def update(dt):
    my_ant.iterate(1) # Run one iteration of Langton's Ant
   
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/1000)
pyglet.app.run()
```

However, this results in the output flickering and the colors blending as well as the simulation not running nearly as fast as it could.  I also tried not tying `on_draw()` into the `window.event` loop and just calling it 60 times a second, but it resulted in the same flickering and speed issue.

```
def draw(): # Don't tie drawing the screen into the event loop
    Ant.batch.draw() # Draw the grid spaces that were changed
    Ant.buffer = [] # Clear the updated grid space buffer

def update(dt):
    my_ant.iterate(1) # Run one iteration of Langton's Ant
   
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/1000)
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(draw, 1/60) # Update the screen 60 times a second

pyglet.app.run()
```

I really like the control that the second approach gives over the timing of the frames and the simulation, so if there is any way to keep that same general approach but fix the flickering it would be great.
I'm new to python/pyglet, so if there is any way to do what I want without writing a custom event loop, that would be nice as well.

[Here](https://github.com/LoneSurvivr314/Langtons-Ant/blob/Render-Update/Langton%27s%20Ant.py) is a link to all the code, all it needs is pyglet installed.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `on_draw` window event, not scheduling your own draw function. You also need to clear the window before you draw.

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    Ant.batch.draw()
    Ant.buffer = []
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  However, the `batch` list only stores the grid squares that have been updated in the last display cycle, so when you call `window.clear` and then draw the batch, it only draws the updated squares, as it is too slow to redraw every square every frame.  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: In your example you only show the updated squares. Did you want to show all of the squares or only the updated ones? I am confused. With the suggestions I made, I get max FPS without any flickering using your code. Is there something else you wanted to accomplish?

Comment: I should have made it clearer in my original post, the reason I want to not clear the screen is that I cannot redraw every square every frame, so I only redraw the updated frames, but want the previously drawn squares (from previous iterations) to stay on the screen.

Comment: Ahhh I gotcha. In that case you need to redo your implementation a little. My recommendation is to create your entire rectangle grid at the start. All 250x250 rectangles. You shouldn't need to keep track of updated rectangles and all of that with this method as batching can handle it. Then each time your ant moves into a square, change the color of it.  The reason your implementation is slow is because you are creating 10k rectangles every second. (1/1000 sec * 10 iterations)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V3HhHdXe  Here is an example based on your code.

Comment: I tested your code and it works great.  Thanks for taking the time to figure out my problem and help solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem comes from the division :(

in Python :

```
1/60 = 0
```

this is an INTEGER division because 1 and 60 are integers, you should write instead :

1.0/60

```
1.0/60 = 0.016666667
```

if you want a floating point division, you have to write explicitly one of the numbers as a float : 1.0

Comment: That didn't work for me. I'm on Python 3, so 3/4 == 3.0/4.0 == .75